# java code generated from wsdl using cxf-codegen plugin version 4.0.3

Tags: soap, java-17, wsdl2java, wsdl.exe

my project is using `cxf-codegen` plugin to generated java code from `wsdl` and the structure of the generated files was as below:

- generated-sources

  - cxf

    - com.example

      - dxl.gr.ws.client.customeragreement
      - group

but when I upgraded the version from 3.5.5 to 4.0.3, the structure of the generated files become different and there are some missing code inside generated classes although I didn't change any thing in wsdl file.

the new structure as below:

- generated-sources

  - cxf

    - com.example

      - group

here is cxf-codegen plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-sources</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
          <wsdlOptions>
            <wjsdlOption>
              <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/CustomerAgreementVBS/WSDL/CustomerAgreementVBS.wsdl</wsdl>
              <wsdlLocation>CustomerAgreementVBS/WSDL/CustomerAgreementVBS.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
              <extraargs>
                <extraarg>-b</extraarg>
                <extraarg>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/CustomerAgreementVBS/WSDL/service_mapping.xml
                </extraarg>
              </extraargs>
              <extendedSoapHeaders>true</extendedSoapHeaders>
            </wjsdlOption>
          </wsdlOptions>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

and here is extraarg `service_mapping.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jaxws:bindings
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        wsdlLocation="CustomerAgreementVBS.wsdl"
        xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions">
        <jaxws:package name="com.example.dxl.gr.ws.client.customeragreement"/>
        <jaxws:enableAsyncMapping>true</jaxws:enableAsyncMapping>
        <handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
            <handler-chain>
            </handler-chain>
        </handler-chains>
    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Does any one know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution was in `service_mapping.xml` file. it should be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jaxws:bindings
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        wsdlLocation="CustomerAgreementVBS.wsdl"
        xmlns:jaxws="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxws">
    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions">
        <jaxws:package name="com.example.dxl.gr.ws.client.customeragreement"/>
        <jaxws:enableAsyncMapping>true</jaxws:enableAsyncMapping>
    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```